# Animate images with same classname separately in css

Tags: html, css

Here's the html:

```
<img class='img-logo' src={logo} alt="Logo" />
<img class='img-logo' src={logo} alt="Logo" />
<img class='img-logo' src={logo} alt="Logo" />
<img class='img-logo' src={logo} alt="Logo" />
```

and the css:

```
.img-logo{
  position: absolute;
  top:4% ;left: 60%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  animation-name:move_up;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes move_up {
  from{top: 38%;}
    to{top:4%}
}
```

can I make them move independently, one after the other without using java script, just css and html

Comment: You can use the pseudo-selector `nth-child()`.

Comment: @Amini yeah, nice, figured it, was hoping i wouldn't have to duplicate the classes too.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it, looks like this:

```
.img-logo:nth-child(2) {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  animation-duration: 10s;
 }
.img-logo:nth-child(3) {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 30%;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes move_up {
  from{top: 38%;}
    to{top:4%}
}
```